# Why mutable lists of different types behave as immutable when put inside a mutable list

Tags: kotlin, mutability, mutablelist

As we know, it is possible in Kotlin to create a mutable list of mutable lists of different types, e.g.:

```
val list = mutableListOf(
            MutableList<Int>(3) { 0 }, 
            MutableList<String>(2) { "aaa" }
        )
```

and it is possible (as expected) to change the main list, e.g.:

```
list.add(MutableList<Double>(4) { 0.0 }
```

and after this operation, the result of `println(list)` is as follows:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [aaa, aaa], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

**BUT IT IS IMPOSSIBLE** to change the sublists,
e.g. the operations:

```
list[0][1] = 2
list[1].add("bbb")
```

produce the error messages:
    *The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Nothing*
and
    *Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Nothing was expected*
respectively...

**MY QUESTIONS ARE**:
*Why these nested sublists - declared as mutable - behave as they were immutable???*
*Is there any way to change these nested sublists???*

By the way...
I've already checked, that nested sublists declared mutable, behave quite normal when they are all of the same type.
It is possible - as expected - to change those nested sublists in that case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MutableList is typed you must let compiler know the exact type of sublist before adding item to it.
Following code:

```
(list[0] as MutableList<Int>)[1] = 2
(list[1] as MutableList<String>).add("bbb")
```

works well. However you can still have problems in runtime when you'll try to cast to a wrong MutableList type, that's why a warning ("Unchecked cast") is reported.

When all sublists are **of the same type** e.g. `Int` the top-level `list` type is unambiguously inferred by compiler as `MutableList<MutableList<Int>>` so you don't have to explicitly tell compiler the type of sublists as it's already aware of them. But when sublists are of different types compiler infers `list`'s type as `MutableList<MutableList<Any>>` and limits you to invoke only non-typed methods of `MutableList` (e.g. `clear()`) without casting.

Comment: thank you @Nikolai! it actually works, but it seems strange to me that you have to cast - after all types of sublists have been explicitly given before

Comment: The reason you have to cast them is the compiler doesn’t know what they are. For the compiler to know what type was in each index of the parent list at any time, it would have to be advanced enough to be able to run an entire simulation of your app’s behavior at runtime. When compilers become that advanced, they will be writing all our code for us.

Comment: I see the Kotlin documentation topic about generics can be useful for understanding this problem - see:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html

Comment: @Tenfour04 - now I think that - to be strict - the compiler (at the source code level) knows what are the types of the sublists, as they were explicitly pointed out...
but - because of the 'type erasure' - the runtime environment (e.g. JVM) doesn't know them, so we have to use explicit casts

Comment: @Nikolai Shevchenko - following your suggestion I've checked the exact inferred type of the ```list```, and it is ```MutableList<out {Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable}>```, and as I guess the 'magic word' ```out``` is responsible for my original problem

Comment: `List` is for collections where every element is the same type. If you need elements of different types, then maybe a data class or tuple or other type would be more suitable?

Comment: It knows what they were at the time you put them in but the compiler can’t possibly know what’s in each index at the time you pull them out because it can’t analyze every possible thing that will happen to the collection in your code and predict that the code where you’re reading the value out always happens after you put it in, and there is no possible way it was changed in between. And if it could, it would be running a whole simulation of your app, keeping arrays of data about every collection that appears anywhere in your code.

Comment: Imagine you have an Array (which do not suffer from type erasure) of mixed types, size 1000. You put a String in at index 3 somewhere in your code and you put a Float in at index 500. Somewhere else in your code you retrieve a value `myArray[500]`. You can clearly see by reviewing your code that there should be a Float returned. But the compiler can’t know that unless it is keeping a full sized array of data about what’s in the array. But it wouldn’t just be storing type information. In every spot in your code where you retrieve a value, it would have to analyze your entire app to ensure…

Comment: that under every possible line of logic, the value cannot possibly be anything other than a Float at this place in code. There are so many things that could change it. Maybe it was passed around to different functions, maybe the order these functions are called varied. These functions could be called multiple times in an infinite combination of orders. The array could be passed out of the class, or we could have a new array in memory that’s replaced what was originally stored in that property, etc. It just makes no sense to imagine the compiler could know what’s in each index always.